# How to set Sails Mongo model name with dots

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I run the command **sails generate model words.common**
It created in the model folder the model file **Words.common.js**

but I got a server error:
The `Words.common` model has an invalid name.
Model names must start with a letter and contain only letters, numbers and underscores.

MongoDB supports collection name with dots. How do I set it correctly in Sails? and how do I call this model from the controller?

I use Sails v1.0

Comment: Post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

i run : **sails generate model wordsCommon**

In the model file I added after the attributes field : **tableName: 'words.common'**

In the controller, I get the model by **WordsCommon** global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Run This Comamnd:  sails generate model userModal your modal name